# Error "Cannot read properties of undefined" while trying to pass data from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have been trying to pass a simple value from the child component to the parent component, but every time I trigger the function passed from parent to child, I get an error: Cannot read properties of undefined. I have looked at examples and I don't see what is wrong. I know a simple dropdown menu could easily be implemented into one component but I want to keep the separate.
Here is the code of the parent component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import "../css/app.css";
import ClassesDropdown from "./ClassesDropdown";

function CreateCharacter() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [race, setRace] = useState("");
  const [classId, setClassId] = useState("1");
  const [level, setLevel] = useState("");
  const [creatorId, setCreatorId] = useState("");
  const [campaignId, setCampaignId] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  const submitPost = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3002/api/characters/create", {
      name: name,
      race: race,
      classId: classId,
      level: level,
      creatorId: creatorId,
      campaignId: campaignId,
      description: description,
    });
  };

  const getClassDropdown = (selectedClass) => {
    setClassId(selectedClass);
    console.log("Class is selected!");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="boxed">
        <span className="formTitle">Create a character:</span>
        <div>
          <label>Name: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setName(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Race: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setRace(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Class: </label>
          <ClassesDropdown onClassFetch={getClassDropdown} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Level: </label>
          <input
            type="number"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setLevel(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Creator:</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setCreatorId(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Campaign: </label>
          <input
            type="number"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setCampaignId(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Description: </label>
          <textarea
            onChange={(e) => {
              setDescription(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Image: </label>
          <input
            type="file"
            onChange={(e) => {
              console.log("Image:", e);
            }}
          />
        </div>

        <button onClick={submitPost}>Create a Character</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateCharacter;
```

And the code of the child component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import "../css/app.css";

function ClassesDropdown({ props }) {
  const [classList, setClassList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3002/api/classes/get").then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      setClassList(data.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const selectHandler = (e) => {
    props.onClassFetch(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select name="classesSelect" onChange={selectHandler}>
        {classList.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <option key={key} value={val.id}>
              {val.class}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ClassesDropdown;
```

I tried just console logging the selected value from the dropdown menu and It is getting the correct value it's just when I try executing props.onClassFetch I get the error.

Comment: What is the full error? Usually it has _"(reading xyz)"_ at the end of it

Comment: Oh, you're destructuring props with `ClassesDropdown({ props })` in your component, but instead should just be using `ClassesDropdown(props)` without the destructuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a minute since I've worked on React, but it seems like the issue might be in how you're destructuring your `ClassesDropdown` function parameters here:

```
function ClassesDropdown({ props })
```

Because you're essentially passing a dictionary to the function when the component gets created in the parent, you can remove the destructuring, like so:

```
function ClassesDropdown(props)
```

The other option is to continue using destructuring, but make the destructured parameter's name consistent with the named argument:

```
function ClassesDropdown({ onClassFetch }) {

  ...

  const selectHandler = (e) => {
    onClassFetch(e.target.value);
  };

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from this

```js
// ..... above code
function ClassesDropdown({ props }) {
  const [classList, setClassList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

//..... below code
```

to this

```
// ..... above code
function ClassesDropdown(props) {
  const [classList, setClassList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

//..... below code
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the {} from the main function worked. Thank you all I didn't see that and thank you for explaining!